# Ruby mixin override method clarification

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I've just faced this behavior I don't really understand.

```
module M
  def foo
    "module_foo"
  end
end

class C
  def foo
    "class_foo"
  end
  include M
end

puts C.new.foo
```

Why does `C.new.foo` actually return `class_foo` ? I was pretty much sure that method should be overridden by the one in module. Another thing, replacing `"class_foo"` with `super` makes `C.new.foo` return `"module_foo"

That actually looks like module is somehow included before the class instance method is defined. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From *Programming Ruby* section on mixins:

> In fact, mixed-in modules effectively behave
>   as superclasses.

So what you experience is normal.
your Module M is a superclass of your class C

Therefore your foo method in class C overrides the foo method in module M

Answer (score 5):

Here's how ruby does method lookup:

1. receiver's singleton class;
2. receiver's class;
3. any included modules methods;
4. repeat lookup in in the receiver's superclass;
5. if no method was found at all, method_missing call;

You can find more details here: http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/ruby_metaprogramming_2.html

> *Therefore, to find a method, Ruby goes in the receiver's class, and from there it climbs the ancestors chain until it finds the method.
>   This behavior is also called the "one step to the right, then up"
>   rule: Go one step to the right into the receiver's class, and then up
>   the ancestors chain, until you find the method. When you include a
>   module in a class (or even in another module), Ruby creates an
>   anonymous class that wraps the module, and inserts the anonymous class
>   in the chain, just above the including class itself.*

Comment: method_missing is not checked until after walking all the ancestors

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, just fixed it!

Comment: 0. receiver's singleton class;

Comment: Note: the singleton class may not even exist as it is created lazily when you decide to add methods to it.